# Como usar corretamente o Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Estou estudando sobre o `RegularExpression`, mas não estou entendendo direito.
Em meu `Model` a propriedade `CPF` deve ser preenchido apenas por números:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "CPF deve conter apenas números")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

Queria entender como validar usando RegularExpression.

Comment: Se deve conter apenas números, porque não usar um `int` em vez duma string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, a expressão não está exatamente certa. O correto seria:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{11}", ErrorMessage = "CPF inválido. O CPF deve conter 11 caracteres e apenas dígitos")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

Isto porque do jeito que estava você está validando apenas um dígito de 0 a 9, e não 11 dígitos.

A validação é feita no cliente. Certifique-se de que o *Bundle* do jQuery Validation esteja adicionado à *View*:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");
}
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui @Cigano, vou postar outra questão sobre usar mask no input, mas usando através do model, se puder me ajudar, obrigado

Comment: Só colar o link aqui pra mim.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100327/inputmask-pelo-model-c-visual-basic @Cigano obrigado por ajudar :)

Comment: **\d** `= [0-9]` vamos lembrar dele :D

Answer (score 2):

Sua validação significa, o valor de entrada de `CPF` deve apenas receber números(ou apenas um) isso é expresso por `[0-9]` o colchete significa que é uma lista, o `0-9` é o intervalo de caractares permitidos.

O problema parece ser que apenas um digito é capturado, um CPF 'normal' tem 11 digitos numéricos(tem aquele outro 'cpf' cic um amarelinho que tem um formato diferente), você pode informar isso através de um quantificador fixo `{11}` que é o número passado entre as chaves.

Comment: Que gramática, hein, jovem?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez qual parte?

Comment: *...o um CPF 'normal' tem 11 digitosn numericos*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez lol, processamento paralelo, obrigado vou corrigir.