# InputMask pelo model

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Olá, estou usando o plugin `jQuery` - `maskedInput`, onde pego o `id` do meu `input` e faço a máscara:

```
$("#CPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
```

está funcionando, só que gostaria de usar esse `mask` através do `model`, sem a necessidade de um `js` externo

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9.-]{14}", ErrorMessage = "CPF deve conter apenas números")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }
```

obrigado

Comment: @Marconi ali so estou tratando o pattern, queria a máscara no input,

Comment: Você quer usar mascara pelo RegularExpression?

Comment: @Marconi , não, tenho o arquivo js 'jquery.maskedinput.js' eu digo que quero usar a máscara no model, assim fica direto, não preciso ficar pegando o #id dos meus inputs, entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, se conseguir montar vai ficar legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade você quer validar o CPF no *Controller*, se entendi bem.

Implemente o atributo de validação do CPF:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class CpfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        int soma = 0, resto = 0;
        string digito;
        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

        string CPF = value.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

        if (CPF.Length != 11)
            return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

        if (Convert.ToUInt64(CPF) % 11111111111 == 0)
            return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

        string tempCpf = CPF.Substring(0, 9);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];

        resto = soma % 11;
        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = resto.ToString();
        tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
        soma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];

        resto = soma % 11;

        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
            resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = digito + resto.ToString();

        if (CPF.EndsWith(digito))
            return null;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Depois decore a propriedade com ele:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9.-]{14}", ErrorMessage = "CPF deve conter apenas números")]
[Cpf]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

Sobre não usar o JS na *View*, é algo que tento há algum tempo fazer e não consigo de uma forma satisfatória. [Fiz esta pergunta há algum tempo atrás](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9616/asp-net-mvc-atributo-que-escreva-em-uma-view), mas que a resposta não chega a 100% do que eu queria.

Comment: Pelo que entendi parece que ele quer deixar a mascara na propriedade CPF do model. Veja nos comentários abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: esse atributo de validação do CPF, onde eu coloco ele? tenho que criar uma class?

Comment: @Marconi Então, por isso coloquei o lance da pergunta que fiz antigamente. Eu também quero saber duma forma mais elegante como fazer. Até hoje não consegui.

Comment: @Furlan Sim. Crie a classe dentro de um diretório do projeto chamado `Attributes`, de preferência.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez se conseguisse fazer isso: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642477/Input-Masking-in-MVC-using-Data-Annotation . Seria a resposta dos problemas kk

Comment: @Furlan Já tentei. Não funciona.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez ah, entao vou usar o jQuery mesmo, pegando o #id de cada elemento e boa, obrigado mais uma vez :)

Comment: Entendi Cigano, nem sabia que tinha como fazer. Muito legal a pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi É capaz que eu tente essa solução do Code Project de novo qualquer dia desses, aí atualizo as duas respostas.

Comment: legal, até eu vou dá um estuda pra saber como funciona isso.

Comment: Ficou muito bom o exemplo do controller, só mudaria o regex para algo como `^\d+{3}\.\d+{3}\.\d+{3}\-\d{2}$`